# UnmarshalException on abstract class

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb, moxy

I have a problem with a webservice, that runs on glassfish 3.1.1, but fails on glassfish 3.1.2.2

```
@XmlSeeAlso({
B.class,
BId.class,
C.class,
CId.class
})
public abstract class A {
private Id id;
}

public abstract class Id {

}

public class B extends A {}

public class C extends A {}

public class BId extends Id {}

public class CId extends Id {}
```

class B get's a BId at runtime, C a CId.

I have several other places, where I have abstract classes and the webservice serialization works just fine and I see a xsi:type qualifier in the generated xml. In this case however, no xsi:type qualifier is added and I get something like:

```
<a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="B">
    <id>
         ...
    </id>
    ...
</a>
```

So the unmarshalling can't identify the type of the id and tries to instantiate an abstract Id instead of a subclass.

My best guess, is that this is a bug in eclipselink moxy that was added to glassfish 3.1.2 (but might be wrong about that)
Anyone got an idea on how to work around this issue?

I already tried adding more @XmlSeeAlso tags, but that didn't help.
I also tried  using @XmlRootElement and @XmlElementRef, but I couldn't get it to generate a getId() method on the generated Stubs for A. The webservice stubs I generate only had methods
getBId and getCId on the class A, instead of a getId that returns the base type.

Comment: MOXy is not the default JAXB implementation in GlassFish 3.1.2.  Unless you configured your service to use MOXy (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/glassfish-312-is-full-of-moxy.html), then you are still using the JAXB reference implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Then I think I'll try to activate moxy and see if that solves my problem.